# Review queue and skip button

Tags: support, review

I just had a quick look at the first-post review queue to see if there were any questions I could helpfully edit.

The answer was no (in the time I had to do so), so I pressed 'skip' for each of these questions. When I returned to the main CV page these posts were then listed on the front page (oops). Is this what usually happens, or do these posts actually stay in the review queue for other users (and just show up on my front page)?

The questions in point were the three following ones: I added some further-details-please comments to the latter two just in case they had in fact popped out of all the review queues...apologies for any additional work.

[Does this discrete distribution have a name?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/152761/16974)

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152760/gaussian-processes-cubic-correlation-model

[Chi-squared vs ANOVA test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/152758/16974)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't worry, you're not going to hurt anything by clicking `Skip`. Thanks for doing your bit to help. It's appreciated.

Clicking `Skip` means "I can't decide, let someone else look at it". So if you weren't clear on whether those were okay, that was the right thing to do. The fact that the post was visible on the main page was not a consequence of you clicking `Skip`.

The second post you mention also was automatically put into the "Low Quality" queue and is also now in the "Close" queue, so it will be getting multiple sets of eyes pass over it.

A few comments on the "First Post" queue -- since people asking their first question or posting their first answer won't generally know how the system works their stuff is put into a review queue, so more experienced people like yourself will take a closer look. The idea is to look for a number of things like

- does the question or answer meet the site standards (on topic, clear, etc*)?
- if a question, is the title clear and relevant? 
  (will it help others with a similar question to find this post?)
- is it appropriately tagged?

(not a complete list!)

* it's also a great place to spot the occasional spam posts

Depending on what you see you might comment to guide the poster**, or edit, or vote to close/flag for moderator attention, and so on

**  (pointing out a relevant page of help, for example, or seeking clarification)

Once you finish taking all the actions you think are needed, click `I'm Done`. If it has no obvious problems, you click `No Action Needed`$^\dagger$, and as mentioned already, if you really don't know, click `Skip` and no harm done.

$^\dagger$ (even if it ends up out of the first post queue as a result, other people can still see the post on the normal "new" and "active" pages, so if you get this wrong once in a while it still doesn't matter very much.)

Comment: Thanks Glen_b, much appreciated to know that all was working as intended. I did realise I could make some of the suggestions along the lines of what you have written above (in terms of elucidating further information) that didn't require any rocket-stats.